# Setting caret position with multiple contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

Here are two contenteditable divs. The caret is at 5th character in the second div and when user press up-arrow key, I want to move caret to 5th character in the last line in the first dive. Is there any way to make this? Notice that the first div only has one text node.

```
<div contenteditable="true"> Some long text.... </div>
<div contenteditable="true"> short text </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I wrapped contenteditable divs in another contenteditable div and set false for wrapper div. When your press keyboard up or down, set wrapper div's contenteditable true and set false again in keyup event.